# How to convert python 3d list to ragged tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ragged

I am using the following code:

```
def ragged_from_3Dlist(list3d):
    values = [item for list2d in list3d for list1d in list2d for item in list1d]
    lens2d = [len(list1d) for list2d in list3d for list1d in list2d]
    lens1d = [len(list2d) for list2d in list3d]
    return tf.RaggedTensor.from_nested_row_lengths(values, [lens1d, lens2d])
```

Is there any better approach ?

Comment: `tf.ragged.constant(list3d)`?

Comment: Thanks, it works